# Migration from Evernote Job to Workmanager

Tags: android, evernote, android-workmanager, android-job

We are using https://github.com/evernote/android-job for our app for background sync. Now we have planned to move to Workmanager.

My question is, with our new build we will include classes related to workmanager and remove classes related to android-job along with evernote library. For our existing users, once they upgrade to this new version, if the old job gets fired, what will happen? if the app crashes during invocation?

Is this a good practice to remove the job related files during upgrade?

Comment: We are in the same process - Can you let us know  how you have handled updates ?

Comment: Yes we were able to remove the evernote related files from  the build. App did not crash after upgrade.